# Latex symbol for right arrow with circular and diamond shaped tail

Tags: arrows

I want to create a right arrow with a circle on its tail and a diamond on its tail. How is it possible? Please help.

Comment: For future symbol problems, that might occur, you may want to have a look at [The Comprehensive Latex Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive). Sadly I did not find the symbol what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*\circarrow{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\hspace{.81ex}$\rightarrow$}{$\circ$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand*\diamondarrow{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\hspace{.83ex}$\rightarrow$}{$\diamond$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand*\diamondcircarrow{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\hspace{.88ex}$\circarrow$}{$\diamond$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand*\circdiamondarrow{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\hspace{.86ex}$\diamondarrow$}{$\circ$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\( A \mathrel{\circarrow}B \quad C\mathrel{\diamondarrow} E \)

\( A\mathrel{\circdiamondarrow}B  \quad C\mathrel{\diamondcircarrow}E\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but `\def` shouldn't be used and there should be `\mathrel{...}` around the arrow in the definition. We don't want to teach bad habits to newcomers, do we? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg  I debated `\mathrel` but didn't know how he wanted to use it (of course, I used it that way, so I should at least put it around my particular usage).  He might want it for a map legend, for all I know.  Also, I can use some instruction here, since I'm not sure what you mean by not using `\def`.

Comment: In general `\newcommand` should be preferred for user level macros. Using `\def` exposes to every kind of evil.

Answer (score 3):

I understood the question in the way, that one arrow should have a circle and a diamond at its tail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*{ring and diamond}{ring and diamond}{open diamond}{open diamond}{o}{o}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ringdiamondarrow}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[ring and diamond->](0,0)--(2em,0);}}}
\begin{document}
\(a\ringdiamondarrow b\)
\end{document}
```

[image]