# Arrow with plus on tail in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I've been Googling for ages and can't find this answer. The only thing that even gets close to asking what I'm wanting is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123738/latex-symbol-for-right-arrow-with-circular-and-diamond-shaped-tail) but I don't quite get the answer.  How in the world does `\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine` work?

Anyway, I want to make an arrow in a TikZ picture that looks like `+---->`.  Like a normal arrow, but with a plus sign at the beginning.

Comment: do you want an arrow head as a plus sign? or combine it with something?

Comment: A line can have an arrow head in either end like this e.g.: `<----->`. Combining arrowheads looks e.g `----->o>`. It does not seem like you want to combine anything. Do not use google - read the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution that scales with line width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{+ /.tip = {Bar[sep=1.5pt 2,width=3pt 4]_[sep=0]}}

\begin{document}

\tikz\draw[+->] (0,0) -- (1,0);

\tikz[very thin]\draw[+->] (0,0) -- (1,0);

\tikz[very thick]\draw[+->] (0,0) -- (1,0);

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "new-style" `arrows.meta` version...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[+/.tip = {%
  .
  _[sep=2pt 2]% Comment out this line for no gap between the line and the +
  Bar[sep=-1.5pt -2, length=0pt 1, width=3pt 3]
  Bar[sep=0pt 0, length=3pt 3,width=0pt 1]
}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
  \draw [line width=\i/10, +-Stealth] (0,\i/2) -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...and an "old-style" arrows version (the old way is deprecated and less flexible than the new `arrows.meta` stuff - but still work and are a bit simpler to create):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{plus}{plus}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=1pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by1.25\pgflinewidth
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+0pt}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+3\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=1pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by1.25\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetmiterjoin
  \pgfsetbuttcap
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.0\pgfutil@tempdima}{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.0\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{1.0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\pgfdeclarearrow{name=+-+, means=plus}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
  \draw [line width=\i/10, +-stealth] (0, \i/2)  -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With TikZ:

```
   \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) node {+} --++(4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) node {\rotatebox{30}{+}} --++(30:4);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]