# Arrow tail style using tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

For my `tikz-cd` diagrams, I am trying to define an arrow with a cross at the tail. I feel like this should be easy, but have not found an easy way of doing this yet.

Comment: A cross like in + or x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Rays` arrow tips from the `arrows.meta` Ti*k*Z library:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, arrows.meta}

% '+' arrow tip
%
% You may declare the '+' arrow tip centrally here if you wish, or in a
% particular 'tikzpicture' environment as shown below.
% Thanks to Håkon Marthinsen for this arrow tip specifiation
% (<https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340406/73317>).
%
%\tikzset{+ /.tip = {Bar[sep=1.5pt 2,width=3pt 4]_[sep=0]}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, {Rays[]}->, "\phi"] & B \\
                                            & C
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, {Rays[n=8]}->, "\phi"] & B \\
                                               & C
\end{tikzcd}

% '+' arrow tip from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340406/73317>
\begin{tikzcd}[+ /.tip = {Bar[sep=1.5pt 2,width=3pt 4]_[sep=0]}]
 A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, +->, "\phi"] & B \\
                                     & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What about an “upright cross”?

Comment: Dear @egreg, please consult the latest version of my answer. It features what I would call a  '+' arrow tip—I don't mind if you want to call it an “upright cross”. :-)

Comment: Exactly what I meant, thanks!

Comment: @egreg I shall take a screenshot of your comment and keep it locked in a safe like a check from Don Knuth. ;-)