# Turnstile arrow in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, turnstile

I want to produce a "turnstile" ie `\vdash` style arrow in tikz-cd.

I can do it with option `[maps to, no head]` but then the vertical bar appears too short:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r, maps to, no head, "F"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What is the simplest way to add a longer vertical bar to the tail?

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code of your attemp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler solution, combining ideas from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495412/arrow-tail-style-using-tikz-cd):

```
\begin{tikzcd}[| /.tip = {Bar[scale=2]}]
A  \arrow[r, |-]  B
\end{tikzcd}
```

Also, the first answer has the problem that it changes all diagrams in the document, but this one affects only the current diagram.

Comment: Can I ask you what changes all diagrams?

Comment: @Alenanno:  It seems that your solution changes all the arrows in subsequent diagrams....?

Answer (score 8):

You were quite close, I changed `maps to` to `tail`, not a huge difference in the result, but in my case you're just saying "I want the tail" rather than "I want this arrow". We will be keeping the `no head`.

The major change, or rather addition, I did was to add a style to `tikzcdset`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % no need to load tikz, since tikz-cd already loads it

% \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % you can uncomment this if you want more arrow types

\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={>={|[scale=2]}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r, tail, no head,"F"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain the `diagrams` line?  It seems to have changed the tail shape, otherwise it would not be a vertical line.

Comment: @YanKingYin Sure! The `diagrams` command is used to change the style of the diagrams, I used it for the arrow appearance for example. So it's `diagrams={ <options> }`. Inside of it, I said `>=` which means "arrow tip is". Then with `{|[scale=2]}`  I specify the arrow tip `|` with a scale to make it bigger. If you remove "no head", you'll see the arrow will look like `|----|`. I couldn't find an option to define only the tail and there might not be one. You can see more in the [`tikz-cd` manual](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf)

Comment: Let me know if something is still unclear.