# Turnstile arrow in.....xy package

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix, turnstile

Following the previous question [Turnstile arrow in tikz-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567532/turnstile-arrow-in-tikz-cd), now I am curious how I can increase the `left tail` with the `xy` package. In the documentation I haven't found anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{A\ar@{|-}[r]^F&B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]