# Scaling symbol when used in subscript

Tags: symbols, subscripts, scaling

I'm using this symbol (defined by Steven B. Segletes [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123738/latex-symbol-for-right-arrow-with-circular-and-diamond-shaped-tail)) to denote a special type of function definition:

```
\newcommand*\diamondarrow{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\hspace{.83ex}$\rightarrow$}{$\diamond$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
```

I have noticed that when used in subscript it does not scale (should it, right?). How can I make it scaling automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand*\diamondarrow{%   
  \stackengine{0pt}{\hspace{.83ex}$\rightarrow$}{$\diamond$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\begin{document}
$A \diamondarrow B_{C \diamondarrow D_{E \diamondarrow F}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a different definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\diamondarrow}{%
  \mathrel\diamond
  \mathrel{\mathchoice{\mkern-2mu}{\mkern-2mu}{\mkern-2.5mu}{\mkern-3mu}}%
  \rightarrow
}

\begin{document}
$A \diamondarrow B_{C \diamondarrow D_{E \diamondarrow F}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

By setting everything to a `\mathrel`, TeX will not introduce any additional spacing. With the help of `\mathchoice` we're able to define different negative kerns for the different math styles. This is font depending, though, so different math fonts might need different amounts.

Comment: It works perfectly!