# Rightwards open-headed arrow with circle tail in math mode

Tags: math-mode

How can I define the rightwards open-headed arrow with a circle tail symbol (small o followed by the ⇾ arrow) for math mode, similar to the `\hookrightarrow` or the `\rightarrowtail` symbols?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by an open-headed arrow, but here is a `tikz` solution:

[image]

You can adjust the size of the circle and the triangle however you wish, or change the triangle to a different tip shape, for example, `Latex[open]` or just `to` (for the same arrowhead as `\to`). You can also adjust the length of the arrow, currently set to 5mm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\circrightarrow}{\mathrel{\tikz{
    \draw[{Circle[open, length=3pt]}-{Triangle[open, length=4pt]}](0,0)--(.5,0)}}}

\begin{document}

$A\circrightarrow B$

\end{document}
```